# Sync only files after a specific time with rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a server from which I want to copy files and directories to a local destination.  The local destination does not have any of the files or directories on it.  Instead of copying all files on the server to the local machine, I would like to only update any new files that are put on the server to the local destination.

Thus, I'm assuming that a time stamp of some sort could be used to filter the preexisting files for a rsync transfer.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do that would be to use `rsync` with `find`.

```
rsync <options> <source> <destination>
rsync -azv username@server:'$(find source_dir/ -mmin -120 -type f)' destination_dir/
```

This command will compress and archive files found under source_dir on server that were modified in the last 2 hours and rsync them to destination_dir (local destination). You may have to modify this command to suit your needs.

Comment: This breaks if files have a space in their name.

Comment: It would be better to use something like `--files-from` parameter, this command smells like it's just waiting to blow up.

Comment: So are there any other methods to go about doing this?